# Dynamically reconfigure the inflation radius

Tags: ros-indigo, dynamic-reconfigure

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi y'all,
I've been dealing with this issue for a while now and I just can't quite seem to get anywhere with it.  I'd like to dynamically reconfigure the robot's inflation radius without using the rqt_reconfigure gui.  I'd like to be able to send the robot a message if it's velocity drops below a certain limit, and lower the inflation radius.  I understand that this will also make the robot more likely to bump into objects, so this is just in case the robot gets trapped.
I'm using ROS Indigo, Thanks for reading!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/318682/dynamically-reconfigure-the-inflation-radius/) by [cheesyboi](https://answers.ros.org/users/40500/cheesyboi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2019-03-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Node to help: http://wiki.ros.org/dynamic_reconfigure

There is a tutorial for how to do this as well:  http://wiki.ros.org/dynamic_reconfigure/Tutorials

This question and answer will help you a lot if you want to do it in C++. NOTE: the push_back use in the answer code creates issue but the rest of it is good. I used this as a start for my code below : https://answers.ros.org/question/12276/is-there-a-c-api-for-a-dynamic-reconfigure-client/

You'll see move base has a service called "/move_base/set_parameters". That is the service call you'll substitute into code below.

And finally how I do it in C++ for raspicam node. I am using integers. You'll need to use floats or doubles for inflation radius.

```
#include <dynamic_reconfigure/DoubleParameter.h>
#include <dynamic_reconfigure/Reconfigure.h>
#include <dynamic_reconfigure/Config.h>

    dynamic_reconfigure::ReconfigureRequest srv_req;
    dynamic_reconfigure::ReconfigureResponse srv_resp; 
    dynamic_reconfigure::IntParameter integer_param;
    dynamic_reconfigure::Config conf;

    int cameraControl(int ss, int iso)
    {
      conf.ints.resize(2);
      ROS_INFO_STREAM("ROBOT-STATE: cameraControl: shutter_speed: " << ss << "\tISO : " << iso);
      integer_param.name = "shutter_speed";
      integer_param.value = ss;
      conf.ints.at(0) = integer_param;

      integer_param.name = "ISO";
      integer_param.value = iso;
      conf.ints.at(1) = integer_param;
      srv_req.config = conf;

      ros::service::call("/raspicam_node/set_parameters", srv_req, srv_resp);

      return 1;
    }
```

---

Originally posted by [billy](https://answers.ros.org/users/26871/billy/) with karma: 1850 on 2019-03-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0